# How to solve "RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty. Add operations to the graph before calling run()"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow, I have a class that describes my neural network and all the methods i need for the network. I have a specific method to feed a neuron value. I have declared the neuron initially as a placeholder, hoping to use `get_neuron` method to feed the value to neuron when available. When I am running , I am having a runtime error saying `RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run()`. Can anyone help me how to solve it ? and what exactly it means ? I dont understand what exactly it means by add operations as I have been using `feed_dict` operation and running the session. Also does it bring any disadvantages if i run sessions for every computation to my tensor or should the session only be run at the end when having the final output. I am asking this because i am wondering whether this effects the effectiveness of tensorflow as it follows the graph to optimize while using optimizer.

```
def get_neuron(self, a, b):
        #'while a being the name of the neuron and b being the value of that neuron'
        with tf.Session() as sess_n:
            sess_n.run(a, feed_dict={a: b})
        return
```

EDIT:
this is how I am calling that above function i.e. 
`knowledge_out = knowledge.run(carollis_inp)`
knowledge is a object created from class knowledge_transfer which has a method `run`, and the very first line of the function is 
`self.get_neuron(self.neuron_input, carollis_input)`
The error displayed exactly is

```
[ERROR] [1566241992.292524, 15.300000]: bad callback: <function joint_callback at 0x7f42221982f0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 748, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg, cb_args)
  File "/home/microbot/catkin_ws/src/spider/spider_control/control1.py", line 60, in joint_callback
    knowledge_out = knowledge.run(carollis_inp)
  File "/home/microbot/catkin_ws/src/spider/spider_control/knowledge_transfer.py", line 99, in run
    self.get_neuron(self.neuron_input, carollis_input)
  File "/home/microbot/catkin_ws/src/spider/spider_control/knowledge_transfer.py", line 81, in get_neuron
    sess_n.run(a, feed_dict={a: b})
  File "/home/microbot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/microbot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1098, in _run
    raise RuntimeError('The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the '
RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().
```

EDIT2:
I have a neural network with name knowledge_transfer, it takes 8 inputs and gives four outputs which are then soft maxed , kind of like multi-classification problem. There is this class method `run` which accepts the input array of size 8 and then returns the output array of size four. Inside the `run` method it feeds the given input arguments to input placeholder of a size 8 and then does some processing through the layers and weights and finally gives the output.
example:
 I want to create a class member method which takes two inputs and feed_dict first second input argument to the first argument considering the first argument is a placeholder and both the arguments are of same size.

Edit3: 
I am feeding an input to the input layer, and then using an input function to calculate the output of input layer, later feeding it to input function of hidden layer and then using the output of input function to hidden layer to pass through leaky_rectified linear output , the output of which is then passed to input function of output layer folowed by passing the output of it through softmax function and giving that softmax output as an output of NN.

The code is as follows:

```
        self.neuron_input = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(self.neurons, 1))
        self.weight_in = tf.get_variable(name="Weight_input", dtype=tf.float32, shape=[self.neurons, 1], initializer=self.weight_initer)
        self.neuron_hid = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(int(self.neurons/2), 1))
        self.weight_initer1 = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=1.0, stddev=0.01)
        self.weight_hid = tf.get_variable(name="Weight_hidden", dtype=tf.float32, shape=[self.neurons, 1], initializer=self.weight_initer1)
        self.neuron_out = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(4, 1))
        self.weight_initer2 = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=2.0, stddev=0.01)
        self.weight_out = tf.get_variable(name="Weight_output", dtype=tf.float32, shape=[4, 2], initializer=self.weight_initer2)
        self.bias_initer =tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0-1, stddev=0.01)
        self.bias_in  =tf.get_variable(name="Bias_input", dtype=tf.float32, shape=[self.neurons, 1], initializer=self.bias_initer)
        self.bias_initer1 =tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0-2, stddev=0.01)
        self.bias_hid = tf.get_variable(name="Bias_hidden", dtype=tf.float32, shape=[self.neurons, 1], initializer=self.bias_initer1)
        self.bias_initer2 =tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0-3, stddev=0.01)
        self.bias_out = tf.get_variable(name="Bias_output", dtype=tf.float32, shape=[4, 1], initializer=self.bias_initer2)
```

and then the run() function is as follows:

```
 def run(self, carollis_input):
        self.normalization(carollis_input)
        #'finding the output of the input layer'
        knowledge_input = tf.add(tf.multiply(self.neuron_input, self.weight_in), self.bias_in)

            #'calculating the input for the hidden layer'
        knowledge_hidden = tf.add(tf.multiply(knowledge_input, self.weight_in), self.bias_hid)
        #'calculating the output of hidden layer'
        knowledge_hidden_output = 3.14*(tf.add(tf.multiply(knowledge_hidden, self.weight_hid), self.bias_hid))#input function of hidden layer
        knowledge_hidden_out = tf.nn.leaky_relu(self.neuron_hid, alpha=0.01, name='leaky_relu')
        with tf.Session() as sess1_2:
            sess1_2.run(knowledge_hidden_out, feed_dict={self.neuron_input: carollis_input, self.neuron_hid: knowledge_hidden_output})
        #'calculating the input of output layer'
        tf.reshape(knowledge_hidden_out, [4, 2])#for quadrant method
        in_out = tf.add(tf.multiply(knowledge_hidden_out, self.weight_out), self.bias_out)
        with tf.Session as s:
            s.run(in_out)
        #'finding the softmax output of the neurons'
        softmax_output = np.array(4)
        softmax_output = self.out_softmax(in_out)  # this gives the softmax output and stores it in the newly created array
        return softmax_output
```

The error is as follows :

```
    sess1_2.run(knowledge_hidden_out, feed_dict={self.neuron_input: carollis_input, self.neuron_hid: knowledge_hidden_output})
  File "/home/microbot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/microbot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1098, in _run
    raise RuntimeError('The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the '
RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().
```

Comment: Please the relevant part of your code. Otherwise it is impossible to figure out from where the error is coming from.

Comment: I am sorry I have added the exact error and tracking down the error, i believe that particular session in that function is causing that error. Please let me know if you need any specific details , as I am confused what exactly you  meant by part of the code as I have posted what i believed is relevant to avoid the hassle of going through all the code.

Comment: Can you create a small reproducible example? For a problem to be solved by someone, it has to be reproduced first.

Comment: I have tried to describe the rudiment version of my code and an example describing what exactly i want to do with this particular mentioned function. I am wondering whether feed_dict is considered as an operation or not, from my knowledge it is also an operation, so why is it saying the graph is empty . Do I need to initialize the graph in first place from ```tf.graph``` before i run any sessions

Comment: The error indicates that you are trying to run nodes in the graph that do not exist. Without having a look at your code I can't tell more.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your quick reply, as asked I have updated my code. can you please have a look at edit3 and let me know the problem ? I have been struggling to understand it precise. Thank you